Is there a reason why the dictionaries do not include the word "teleoperation"
A major factor in the strength of English is its ability to adapt to new technological terms. Robotics is a field with a lot of new terminology. As part of my academic studies, I have encountered the term "teleoperation" a lot. Despite understanding the term, I am confused about why this word is not included in numerous dictionaries. For instance, in the Cambridge dictionary, it spills out this result

We have these words with similar spellings or pronunciations: re-operation, teleportation, etc.

For Longman dictionary, it says

Did you mean: teleportation, teleportations, celebration, etc.

For Oxford English dictionary, it mentions

teleoperation, n: The operation of mechanical devices and systems by remote control.

The Oxford dictionary has some technical definitions, but the word doesn't seem to be highlighted as a new word in English.
What is the reason for not adding teleoperation as a new English word?

It generally takes a few years for new words to get into dictionaries. They wait until it becomes clear that the word is likely to stick around.

And general purpose disctionaries often don't have terms that are only used within industries. If you've encountered it in your studies, I'll bet you're studying robotics. Few people outside that industry will encounter it these days.

FYI, it is in the full OED.

For close voters, my opinion is that this question doesn't belong on the meta site. May be "English Language and Usage" stack exchange.

I voted to close it because I think it belongs on [elu.se]. It's more general than just learning the language.

@Barmar, when I try to see the reason, it says the suggested site is the meta. But I agree with you totally.

Maybe I misread the option.

BTW, there's a good book Word by Word: The Secret Life of Dictionaries that describes the process of dictionary creation.

Why?  Because the word has limited currency.

For a word to be considered for addition to an English dictionary, various criteria have to be met. Usually:

Widespread Usage
Consistency of Meaning
Longevity
Cultural Relevance
Recorded Evidence

"Teleoperation", as a robotics term, does not have widespread usage - it is not likely to be known outside of the fields of robotics. Anecdotally, I am a native British English speaker who has worked in STEM fields (not robotics) for 32 years and I have never heard the term until now. So that's the first criterion not met.
The term would have to be popularised for it to be considered worthy of a dictionary entry. As an example, internet-related terms (including the word "internet" and other terms like DNS) only began to appear in dictionaries in the mid-1990s, even though the internet was created in the 1960s and the domain naming system in 1983. But the 'dot-com boom' in the 1990s changed these terms from technical jargon into everyday terms, and that's when they warranted a dictionary definition.

Dictionaries are huge, labyrinthine projects that take huge amounts of effort and resources to maintain. The Oxford English Dictionary is probably the most complete (and well funded) and is updated most frequently.
As noted by Barmar, the "teleoperation" is a highly specialised word (though Wiktionary has had a page for it since 2008). Whilst the OED does note that it has been in use since 1916, it has only occured in very niche contexts.
It is likely that other dictionaries simply haven't got there yet. Most modern dictionaries have large corpora and monitor new words rising in usage, such as Merriam-Webster. You are still welcome to contact the dictionaries and ask for more information.
